# One column form vs. too many fields

Tags: forms

Generally, one column form is considered the best practice for form design. However, when the form has too many fields it wouldn't look good to create a super long form that spans 3+ screens either. For business/patient information, breaking down the form down into steps or collapsible parts are not great solutions as well. Shall I just use a multiple-column form instead?

Comment: I think one column is consider the best practice for form design on mobile... on desktop there are more uses when multiple columns could work better.

Answer (score 1):

That depends on what you mean by 'multiple column'. Multiple columns work especially well when the form inputs within a row are related. For example:

```
| First Name     | Middle Name     | Last Name      |

| Address                                           |
| City           | State           | Post Code      |

| Employer       | Start Date      | End Date       |
```

You can see how this makes better use of the space, and gives a visual organization to each section of the form.

On the other hand, if you mixed and matched form inputs within a single row the form would be extremely confusing and my hunch is many would abandon.

Comment: so are you saying that it's better to have a long form with a single column than mixing and matching fields just to try to shorten the page?

Comment: Within reason, yes. If it's too long, splitting the form into multiple pages might need to be considered.